# How to fix this bug with React Link and Routes

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, routes

This is the code were the Links are not active in the browser:
I think I might be utilizing incorrectly the Link components and the Route components.
All the components of this App are written correctly and they render in other configurations but I would like to use the Toolbar component and be able to activate this links with Routes and so on.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';
import Composers from '../components/Composers';
import Composer1 from '../components/Composer1';
import Composer2 from '../components/Composer2';
import QuienesSomos from '../components/QuienesSomos';
import { HashRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Blog2 from '../components/Blog2'
import ForumContainer from '../containers/ForumContainer'
import HeaderContainer from '../components/HeaderContainer'
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import NavBar from '../components/NavBar'
import { CenterFocusStrong } from '@material-ui/icons';
import { Switch} from 'react-router-dom'



const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  toolbar: {
    borderBottom: `1px solid ${theme.palette.divider}`,
  },
  toolbarTitle: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  toolbarSecondary: {
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    overflowX: 'auto',

  },
  toolbarLink: {
    padding: theme.spacing(1),
    flexShrink: 0,
  },
  div: {
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }
}));

export default function Header(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { sections, title } = props;

  return (
  
    <React.Fragment>
      <Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>
        <Button size="small">Subscribe</Button>
        <Typography
          component="h2"
          variant="h5"
          color="inherit"
          align="center"
          noWrap
          className={classes.toolbarTitle}>
          {title}
        </Typography>
        <IconButton>
          <SearchIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <Button variant="outlined" size="small">
          Sign up
        </Button>
      </Toolbar>
      <Toolbar component="nav" variant="dense" className={classes.toolbarSecondary}>
        <Link to='/quienessomos'>  Quienes Somos  </Link>
        <Link to='/compositores'>  Compositores  </Link>
        <Link to='/blog'>  Blog  </Link>
        <Link to='/forum'>  Forum  </Link>
        <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/quienessomos'> <QuienesSomos/></Route>
        <Route exact path='/compositores'> <Composers/></Route>
        <Route exact path='/composer1'> <Composer1/></Route>
        <Route exact path='/composer2'> <Composer2/></Route>
        <Route exact path='/blog'> <Blog2/></Route>
        <Route exact path='/forum'> <ForumContainer/></Route>
        </Switch>
      </Toolbar>      
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

Header.propTypes = {
  sections: PropTypes.array,
  title: PropTypes.string,
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by "its not active"? Screenshot of what's happens normally helps

Comment: I mean that the links appear in the web page but for some reason when clicked it does not connects you and transfer you to the adequate page of the adequate component.

Comment: I think it has to do with when/where the links are defined. If you implement it the way Airat recommended you should be in a position to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

1. Link is used Here but it is not a Link component from material-ui, I use `import { Link } from ' react-router-dom'`. If you want to style your menu then I suggest you read here https://material-ui.com/guides/composition/#link.
2. as Far as I can tell from my little experience, shoving your navbar and main content into one component is a bad practice, separate your components (menu and main content), into different functions, and preferably into different files.
3. As I understand it, you need to wrap your application in `import { Router } from 'react-router-dom'`.

```
export default function Header (props) {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const { sections, title } = props

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Router>
        <Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>
          <Button size='small'>Subscribe</Button>
          <Typography
            component='h2'
             
            ...

          <Link to='/compositores'> Compositores </Link>
          <Link to='/blog'> Blog </Link>
          <Link to='/forum'> Forum </Link>
        </Toolbar>
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/quienessomos'>
            <div>quienessomos</div>
          </Route>
          <Route path='/compositores'>
            <div>compositores</div>
          </Route>
          <Route path='/composer1'>
            <div>composer1</div>
          </Route>
          <Route path='/composer2'>
            <div>composer2</div>
          </Route>
          <Route path='/blog'>
            <div>blog</div>
          </Route>
          <Route path='/forum'>
            <Forum />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
`
```